# fitting distribution to values (some of which are negative)

Tags: r, probability, distributions, weibull-distribution

I'd like to fit a distribution.

```
library(fitdistrplus)

x1 <- c(20, 9, 2, 1, 0, -5, 6, 3, -3, 0, -3, -2, -4, -3, 5, -2, -1, 
        -11, -35, -35, -36, -37, -39, -34, -37, -36, -41, -33, -26, -27, 
        -26, -20, -6, 0, -3, -11, -2, -3, 8, -9, 10, 13, -6, -2, -3, 
        4, 4, 3, -12, 1, -2, -10, -11, -6, 9, 18, 14, 12, 16, 16, 10, 
        12, 18, 17, 1, 3, 10, 10, 11, 9, 0, 9)


hist(x1) ## visualize data

f1 <- fitdist(x1, "weibull") 
# Error in start.arg.default(data10, distr = distname) : 
# values must be positive to fit an Weibull  distribution
```

How can I fit the distribution when my sample has negative values?

Comment: What do the values represent?  Is there a reason that you suspect a weibull distribution is the most appropriate?  If so, you could add 41 to every number (looks like the lowest is -41).  However depending upon what these represent, that might or might not be a very appropriate solution.

Comment: these are a seasonal adjustment to weekly crop conditions. Sometimes the current week is higher than final, sometimes lower, but for this particular week there is a seasonality that it is usually higher. My colleague fitted these changes in Excel and I'm trying to replicate it in R (most of the fits were either normal or some form of generalized extreme value distribution).

Comment: It's unclear how fitting a distribution could be of any help in your analysis.  Could you explain?